# Mongodb how to find how much days ago from a timestamp field

Tags: mongodb, timestamp, days

I was trying to find the number of days ago using the timestamp but  i dont know how to do that ?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5504cc9ddd5af617caae30b3"),
    "session_id" : 1,
    "Timestamp" : "2014-04-07T10:51:09.277Z",
    "Item_ID" : 214536502,
    "Category" : 0
}
```

How I can calculate the number of days ago using the field "Timestamp" ?

Answer (score 4):

You may use `aggregate`, `$project` with `new Date()` on the **Timestamp** field, then do the calculation, something like this:

```
pipe = {
    "$project" : {
        "_id" : 1,
        "daySince" : {
            "$divide" : [
                {
                    "$subtract" : [
                        new Date(),
                        new Date("$Timestamp")
                    ]
                },
                86400000
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

To calculate:

```
db.collection.aggregate(pipeline=pipe)
```

Since **Timestamp** isn't a `ISODate` object, you just need to convert it to one, then subtract to current date, and divide the result by `60*60*24*1000`, then it will be the number of days since today.

You can also change the `new Date()` to what you need to be compared.

#### Updated:

Since I believe the `Timestamp` format might be malformed, alternatively you may use `mapReduce` functions to calculate this:

```
// in your mongo shell using the db

var mapTimestamp = function() { 
    daySince = parseInt(new Date() - new Date(this.Timestamp) / 86400000);
    emit(this._id, daySince); 
}
// since you map reduce only on one field, there's really no need for this
var reduceTimestamp = function (key, value) { return value; }

db.collection.mapReduce(mapTimestamp, reduceTimestamp, {out: "sample"})
```

To show the results:

```
db.sample.find()
```

Comment: I dnt know why it gives me this :

/* 0 */
{
    "$project" : {
        "_id" : 1,
        "daySince" : {
            "$divide" : [ 
                {
                    "$subtract" : [ 
                        ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"), 
                        ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")
                    ]
                }, 
                86400000
            ]
        }
    }
}

Comment: @majdsoud, are you in mongo shell or some sort of clients like **Python** or **JavaScript** which you didn't mention?

Comment: i am using mongo shell   ( via Robomongo )

Comment: @majdsoud, hey just saw your comment, I guess it might due to malformed `Timestamp` which couldn't be converted to mongo `Date`, you may use javascript function via `mapReduce` to do so. I have tested it locally and it works (although locally both above ways work for me). Give it a try and let me know if it doesn't

Comment: This gives a really good approximation. However, in case you want to be ultra precise regarding timezones, it might not always be exact. For instance, in "Europe/Paris" timezone, there are only 23 hours between "2019-03-31" and "2019-04-01".